# Search and replace HTML tag by class name and replace with non-HTML tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, hugo, hugo-shortcode

I want to replace all `div` tags with the class name "figure"

```
<div class="figure">
    <p>Some content.</p>
</div>
```

with a non-HTML tag (in my case it's a [Hugo shortcode](https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/))

```
{{% row %}}
    <p>Some content.</p>
{{% /row %}}
```

It's easy to [replace html tags with other html tags](https://gist.github.com/cbcafiero/c363006a36672d6803cbdee836af97ef), but I have no idea how to do it if there are non-html tags involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see "easy" solution, because the shortcodes can contain `/`, `<`, `>` characters as well, so you cannot have them as part of the document tree.

One solution is to replace the `<div class="figure">` with custom tag and at the final replace these custom tags with your shortcodes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<div>
    <div class="figure">
        <p>Some content.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="figure">
    <p>Some other content.</p>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.select('div.figure'):
    t = soup.new_tag('xxx-row')
    t.contents = div.contents
    div.replace_with(t)

s = str(soup).replace('<xxx-row>', '{{% row %}}')
s = s.replace('</xxx-row>', '{{% /row %}}')

print(s)
```

Prints:

```
<div>
{{% row %}}
<p>Some content.</p>
{{% /row %}}
</div>
{{% row %}}
<p>Some other content.</p>
{{% /row %}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Notepad or any other text editor that has `search and replace`

functions you can just replace

`'<div class="figure">'` with `'{{% row %}}'` and `'</div>'` with `'{{% /row %}}'`.

Comment: This won't work as there can be other end `</div >` tags as well :)

Comment: Sure there are more divs with different classes.

Comment: Not possible. How would you separate the `</div>` from different classes?